# sinon.js : stub call does not increment callCount

Tags: javascript, testing, async-await, sinon, stub

***sinon.js 9.0.2***

In test I create a stub:

**test.js**

```
const myHandler = {
  handle: (some_var_to_pass) => sinon.stub()["resolves"]([{ whatever: "whatever" }]),
};
```

Then hit the actual code from the test as some endpoint request (with `async / await`) which executs the code below:

**code.js**

```
module.exports = (myHandler) => ({
  getStuff: async (req, res, next) => {
  const var1 = "something1";
  const var2 = "something2";
  const my_response = await myHandler.handle()(var1, var2);

  console.log("my response", JSON.stringify(my_response)); //correct, returns { whatever: "whatever"}
  console.log("Executed stub: ", myHandler.handle(some_var_to_pass).callCount); //always returns zero
```

I control that `myHandler.handle` correctly goes through the stub creation and the `my_response` is

```
{ whatever: "whatever"}
```

However, `myHandler.handle().callCount` remains zero (not `undefined`). What am I missing to make it increment correctly? Or I need to actually set `.callCount` return to 1 when I create the stub (would be weird)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't stub `myHandler.handle` method. You only stub the function which `myHandler.handle` method returned. Unit test solution:

`code.js`:

```js
module.exports = (myHandler) => ({
  getStuff: async (req, res, next) => {
    const var1 = 'something1';
    const var2 = 'something2';
    const my_response = await myHandler.handle()(var1, var2);
    return my_response;
  },
});
```

`code.test.js`:

```js
const code = require('./code');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('64468517', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const returnedFn = sinon.stub().resolves([{ whatever: 'whatever' }]);
    const myHandler = {
      handle: sinon.stub().returns(returnedFn),
    };
    await code(myHandler).getStuff();
    expect(myHandler.handle.callCount).to.be.eq(1);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(myHandler.handle);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(returnedFn, 'something1', 'something2');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  64468517
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (13ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 code.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Great, that fixes the tests for `callCount`, thank you. But this way `req` gets lost  - in `code.js` it's *undefined* now, and I need it to assign `var1`, in the actual code it's `const var1 = req.query.something1'`. With the original code `req.query` was accessible - how should I access it now?

Comment: @SwissNavy You can declare the `req`, `res` and `next` variables and pass them into `getStuff` method.

Comment: Thank you. Your code works (also with variables passed) so I accepted your answer. It did not help me with my problem however because I have to follow a slightly different structure of the code in both the test and the code.

Comment: Actually I managed to accommodate your answer into my code.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you have line: `myHandler.handle(some_var_to_pass)`, you initiate new stub, which of course has 0 callCount.

How to solve it: save `myHandler.handle(some_var_to_pass)` to a variable, call and expect using that variable.

Example:

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const myHandler = {
  // Call myHandler.handle() will return sinon.stub which resolves to array object.
  handle: () => sinon.stub()['resolves']([{ whatever: 'whatever' }]),
};

describe('myHandler', function() {
  it('handle', async function() {
    const var1 = 'something1';
    const var2 = 'something2';
    // Get the stub variable.
    const stub = myHandler.handle();
    // const result = await myHandler.handle()(var1, var2);
    // You use stub variable.
    const result = await stub(var1, var2);
    // Make sure the result is correct.
    expect(result).to.deep.equal([{ whatever: 'whatever' }]);
    // Obviously, stub callCount should be 1.
    expect(stub.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

When I run it using mocha at terminal:

```
$ npx mocha index.test.js 


  myHandler
    ✓ handle


  1 passing (3ms)
```